# AppBarLayout scroll when edit text in EditText

Tags: xml, android-edittext, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

My xml layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/story_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When EditText have more line and out of screen, AppBarLayout is scrolled. How can I keep AppBarLayout always visible while add text to EditText?

Answer (score 0):

add this line to EditText layout is save my day:

```
android:isScrollContainer="true"
```